# Active clamp flyback current dip

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, math

There is a [paper](https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/196/Active-Clamp-Flyback-Using-GaN-Power-IC-for-Power-Adapter-Applications.pdf) that discusses the ACF current dip. I have been attempting to derive the equation from the current dip equation following the method provided by the editor.

However, I have encountered a problem. Please see below.

By referring to [Figure 9](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8341100) from the other paper, I can obtain the equivalent circuit during the current dip. Consequently, I have been following this circuit in an attempt to determine the iLr current.

[image]

Below is the process I have followed,

[image]

but the answer I obtained differs from equation 6.

[image]

Is there anyone who knows how to accurately analyze this circuit?